# Can't move layers into layer groups in gimp

Tags: 12.10, gimp

I have an image with 2 layers at the moment, I created a layer group to start organizing stuff before I continue with my design, however, as much as I click and drag the layers to the group nothing happens (or actually the layer floats back to its positions).

I don't know if it is that I'm doing something wrong as I can't select multiple layers either.

I'm running xubuntu 12.10 with gimp 2.8.2 (with whatever plugins, etc that it comes with by default on xubuntu)

Comment: Was this fixed in more recent versions?